# JSoup to extract particular block from multiple block

Tags: html-parsing, jsoup

I'm new to JSoup and my question here is how do I extract particular text from multiple blocks that share the same class and attributes?

For example here I want to extract the information on 3rd row of the HTML. How do I specified on my JSoup code to extract the information on 3rd row?

```
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="2" class="maintitle">Active Stats</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="row2" valign="top"><b>User's local time</b></td>
                <td class="row1">Oct 22 2013, 07:23 PM</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="row2" width="30%" valign="top"><b>Total Cumulative Posts</b></td>
                <td width="70%" class="row1"><b>4</b>
                <br />( 0 posts per day / 0.00% of total forum posts )
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS-selector syntax to specify what row to select.

```
Element e = doc.select("tr:eq(2) td.row2").first();
System.out.println(e.text());
```

will result in

> Total Cumulative Posts

A tip is to at least look through the Jsoup documentation before asking questions.
All this can easily be found in the API.

[Jsoup - Use selector syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)